# how to make this question about blogging more useful?

Tags: discussion, blog

my question on blogging got put on hold for being unclear what help I need.  Fair enough...

**https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272102/blogging-usefully-about-learning-a-new-programming-language**

Then I am trying to understand how this substantially more vague question got through with 41 votes.

**[What techniques help retain programming knowledge?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140423/how-do-you-remember-programming-related-stuff)**

---

In any case, how can I make my question more clear?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-windows

Comment: @gnat possible. one of the responses clearly says **the site is not doing a good job of explaining its scope**

Comment: yeah I've seen this [explained as sort of by-design](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2688/168): "On the smaller sites, I believe the idea is that, since they get less traffic than Stack Overflow, there's not as much of a disincentive to prevent people from posting, since the community can help users fix problems with their posts, or close, flag, and delete." Kinda, _first you try and break your nose and after that we'll tell you to look at [help/on-topic]_